# Is it possible to get % of GC time if I have not enabled "-Xloggc and -XX:-PrintGCTimeStamps"?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jmx, newrelic

I am wondering how **New Relic** is able to report my % of GC time as I have not enabled the  `-Xloggc` and `-XX:-PrintGCTimeStamps`..

Any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

Java always computes the GC information, loggc only determines whether it gets logged to a file or not.  Even if it is not logged to a file it is available via JMX.

Take a look at [this example](http://www.fasterj.com/articles/gcnotifs.shtml).

Answer (score 0):

Pace's answer is correct. One way to do this is to periodically poll each of the registered [GarbageCollectionMXBean](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html) instances. Prime the pump by recording the current system timestamp and the accumulated collection time so far by calling the MXBean's [getCollectionTime()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/management/GarbageCollectorMXBean.html#getCollectionTime%28%29) attribute/method. Each period thereafter, compute the delta in the collection time and the elapsed time from the prior interval. Percent GC time for that garbage collector will be *elapsed-collection-time/elapsed-time X 100*.  More or less....